# Creating PrivateLink Endpoint to IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an instance (provisioned with Hashicorp Vault) inside a private subnet in AWS. Is there a way I can connect that instance to AWS's IAM services via a privatelink endpoint?

I do know for sure that it's possible to do the same for S3 (because I already did it), but I can't find the IAM endpoint, and at this point I'm not sure if it's impossible or if it just has a different name and I can't find it.

Comment: To be sure we don't go down the wrong path... what in IAM are you trying to access?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm trying to deploy with terraform, which asks hashicorp vault for a temporal IAM user and then uses it to create the EC2 instance. So, the end goal is to make sure that vault can create an IAM.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot any ideas? I hope I did explain the problem clearly enough, but if that's not the case, I'll explain further.

Comment: So what you want to do is: Have an instance that's running Hashicorp Vault inside a Private Subnet, to be able to interact(grant, revoke, alter permissions) with AWS IAM and all that done with Terraform?

Comment: @TenorFlyy Yes. The plan is to make Terraform (ran from the machine that is in charge of making the deploys) ask Vault (installed in another machine in the same VPC/subnet) for an AWS IAM. Then Vault should be able to create a new temporal IAM and give it to Terraform. Note that all of this is possible if I enable NAT on the subnet. I was just wondering if that same thing could be possible using Endpoints (as those are cheaper and I don't really need NAT in the subnet).

Comment: I can't give you a 100% correct answer as of now, since I will have to test  this (hopefully today), but unfortunately, it seems you cannot do what you wish right now. In order to access AWS Services from Private subnet you will need this services to be exposed as either GW endpoints or Interface (PrivateLink) endpoints. The list, which I assume you have already checked, is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html . As of now, there doesnt seem to be an option for IAM.

Comment: Oh, bad news :( . Then I guess I'll have to do it via NAT.